# Does God kill happenstance?

Tags: theology

So I'm big into playing videogames, and recently started reading lore of the Elder Scrolls. Some of which is pretty deep. I came across this in the 36 Lessons of Vivec and thought I'd ask for opinions.

"Is not the sudden revelation of corresponding conditions and disparate elements that gel at the moment of the coincidence one of the prerequisites to being, in fact, coincidental? Synchronicity comes out of repeated coincidences at the lowest level. Further examination shows it is the utter power of the sheer number of coincidences that leads one to the idea that synchronicity is guided by something more than chance. Therefore, synchronicity ends up invalidating the concept of the coincidental, even though they are the symptomatic signs that bring it to the surface."

Much like things such as wind, gravity,and time you can't see it, only the effects of it.

So does God kill happenstance?

Comment: Not entirely philosophy as some would say, but in theosophy : [Synchronicity and the Mind of God](https://www.theosophical.org/publications/quest-magazine/1441-synchronicity-and-the-mind-of-god)

Comment: Did not know this site had other options. Apologies.

Comment: No problem. You might get some answers here.  There's no StackExchange Theosophy or Mysticism site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes.

The omnipotence and omniscience of God mean that he is both aware of and capable of manipulating perfectly all the minutia of the universe, with full knowledge of all the consequences that doing so would entail, hence there are no coincidences or accidents, as all things work according to God's plan and design. (Incidentally, the same argument means that God kills libertarian free will.)

**Unless** God somehow limits his own knowledge by his own choice. The belief that God does this is called [Open Theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_theism), a position invented to try to reconcile libertarian free will with Christianity. This would also open the door for happenstance.